# Calculate the distance between two locations in jsp

Tags: jsp, netbeans

How to calculate the distance between two locations in JSP. I am having the co-ordinates of both locations and i just want to know is there any function available for doing this in JSP.

In android, i am using a function like this for calculating the distance between two places:

```
Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, results);
```

How can i achieve something like this in JSP. Is there any jar files i need to add for this. Kindly help me.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate it in Java and don't know how to port this solution to JSP, or you don't know how to do it in plain Java SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formula from here http://www.koordinaten.com/informations/formula.shtml , 
or from here http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_distance_between_two_points_on_a_globe

```
public class DistanceCalculator {  

private double Radius;  

// R = earth's radius (mean radius = 6,371km)  
// Constructor  
DistanceCalculator(double R) {  
   Radius = R;  
}  

 public double CalculationByDistance(GeoPoint StartP, GeoPoint EndP) {  
  double lat1 = StartP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;  
  double lat2 = EndP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;  
  double lon1 = StartP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;  
  double lon2 = EndP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;  
  double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);  
  double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);  
  double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +  
     Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *  
     Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
  double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));  
  return Radius * c;  
}
```

}

Comment: I think the first function in the second link you have provided is sufficient.